# Using ufunc.at on matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
>>> a=np.zeros(10)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I can use [numpy.ufunc.at](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to modify that array in place:

```
>>> np.add.at(a, [0,3], 2)
>>> a
array([ 2.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

If I now try on a matrix, what I assume to be the method does not work:

```
>>> m=np.zeros(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> m
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> np.add.at(m, [(0,0),(1,1)], 2)
>>> m
array([[ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

My expectation based on supplying the list of tuples of `[(0,0),(1,1)]` would be:

```
      [[ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]
```

Any suggestions on what I use as a list of indices in `numpy.ufunc.at` to get that matrix?

Comment: Try `np.add.at(m, zip(*[(0,0),(1,1)]), 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do multidimensional indexing, you don't pass a list of index tuples; you pass a tuple of index lists (or index arrays).

```
indices = ([0, 1], [0, 1])
np.add.at(m, indices, 2)
```

`indices[0]` gives all the first coordinates of the cells you want to modify, and `indices[1]` gives all the second coordinates. Here's an example:

```
In [10]: a = numpy.zeros([4, 4])
In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
In [12]: indices = ([0, 3], [2, 1])
In [13]: numpy.add.at(a, indices, 2)
In [14]: a
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I'm not entirely sure why it works this way. I suppose it might be more convenient once you've gotten the hang of it, or it might make the rules more internally consistent somehow, but I don't have enough experience with multidimensional indexing to say one way or another.

Comment: NumPy indexing is optimized for indexing into an array with lots of points but fewer dimensions. In that case, the index can be a sequence of a few very long arrays. NumPy can compute the array offsets quickly by computing a dot product of the indexing arrays and the strides. If, instead, the index were a list of coordinate tuples or small arrays, then NumPy would be forced to loop in Python through a (potentially) huge list of small arrays and compute the offset for each individually. That would be slower. I think this is the reason why indexing expects one slice or indexing array per axis.

Comment: Also note that the values in the `indices` argument are broadcast.  For example: `np.add.at(a, [[[0],[1],[3]], [0, 2, 3]], np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3))`