# Unexpected behaviour when adapting sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix `M`and an array `a` of locations where I want to increase `M` by one. This array `a` may contain duplicates and whenever an element is `n` times in `a`, I would like to add `n` to the corresponding position in `M`. I did this the following way:

```
from scipy import sparse as sp
M = sp.csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=float)
M[[0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0]] += 1
```

But when I run this, `M[0,0]` is only increased by one, is there an easy method to adapt this?

Comment: Please consider reading numpy's and scipy's docs to understand what's happening here. So the basic pipeline of calculations (for a vectorized approach) might be: A: sort your locations (lex), B: create a 1d-vec of ones, combine dupes in A while summing B in parallel (B's dimension might decrease; some entries might grow from 1 to N), C: Add these B-values while using indexing with A. A much simpler (loop-based approach): just grab every location in a loop and increment (one after another).

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's the way I was doing it but expected that there would be a faster method.
I come from MATLAB, so I always expect matrix-operations to be faster than looping.

Comment: Yes in most-cases. Then just try the first approach of mine (or wait for some experts to present something better).

Answer (score 0):

How does MATLAB handle this?

`numpy` has a special function to handle this repeated index case, the `add.at`

[Using ufunc.at on matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617292/using-ufunc-at-on-matrix)

This hasn't been implemented for `scipy.sparse`.

Since `sparse` sums repeated coordinates when converting from a `coo`  format to `csr` one, I suspect this problem could be cast in a way that takes advantage of that.  In fact the `csr` matrix has a `M.sum_duplicates` method.

I'd have to play around to work out the details.

---

```
In [876]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=float)
In [877]: M
Out[877]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

demonstrating the `np.add.at` action:

```
In [878]: arr = M.A
In [879]: arr[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0]] += 1
In [880]: arr
Out[880]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [883]: arr = M.A
In [884]: np.add.at(arr,[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0]],1)
In [885]: arr
Out[885]: 
array([[ 3.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Adding to `M` produces the same buffered action - with a warning.  Changing the sparsity of a matrix is, relatively expensive.

```
In [886]: M[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0]] += 1
....
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [887]: M
Out[887]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [888]: M.A
Out[888]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

The correct way to do this addition is to make a new sparse matrix with the values that need to be added.  We can take advantage of the fact that `coo` style inputs sum duplicates with converted to `csr`:

```
In [895]: m = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(5,int),([0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0])), shape=M.shape)
In [896]: m
Out[896]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [897]: m.A
Out[897]: 
array([[3, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

now we can add the original and the new one:

```
In [898]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=float)
In [899]: M+m
Out[899]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```